# error when starting android kivy app using mediapipe

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, mediapipe

this is my first entry here means i am also thankful for any advice on how i can improve my postings here.

I am working on an app written in python which i want to build also for Android devices.For this purpose i have:

1. Setup an Ubuntu 20.4 VM
2. Installed  and configured buildozer
3. Written the app with the kivy framework

Building Android APK files with this setup works quit fine for smaller kivy apps with only basic functionalities and dependencies. Unfortunately i also need Googles pose estimation Mediapipe https://mediapipe.dev/.

When i try to run the App on my Android device

`Samsung Galaxy S10+ : CPU Architecture ARMv8-A / arm64-v8a`

i receive the following error:

**Logfile**

[11-28 19:27:08.240 14013:30612 I/python]

```
ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/user/0/sens.app.sensaiapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/mediapipe/python/_framework_bindings.so" is **for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)**
```

**Respective Entry in the Buildozer config file:**

requirements = python3,kivy,opencv,pandas,numpy,**mediapipe**,android

(str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86

android.arch = arm64-v8a

I have also tried to build mediapipe according to the following **guidelines:**
https://github.com/jiuqiant/mediapipe_python_aarch64/blob/main/README.md

Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue and I couldn't find any related issues online so I am stuck now.

Means I would be really thankful if anyone has faced the same issue and give me a hint towards the right solution. Let me know if there is further information I need to provide to draw the full picture for you.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is the description which is unclear please let me know so i can add what is necessary. i d be grateful for any hint

Comment: Any updates? Same issue here